# Why does the input value added after the recursive call is not evaluated in the return statement?

Tags: java, recursion

Sum of all the natural numbers up to *n*.

Adding *n* before recursive call gives out 15 and adding it after the recursive call shows 10.

```
public static int SumThem(int n){
    if(n==0){
        return n;
    }
    return SumThem(--n) + n;
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    int x = SumThem(5);
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

Output: 10.

The output is 10 which means, while returning, the value for n=5 is not evaluated in the return statement. It only works up to n=4, but as soon as the *n* is added before the recursive call it works fine.

```
public static int SumThem(int n){
    if(n==0){
        return n;
    }
    return n + SumThem(--n);
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    int x = SumThem(5);
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

Output: 15

n=5 does count here. Why is this happening?

Comment: Ask yourself why you are using a modifying operator on `n` in the first place. Then think about what order the evaluation happens in

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are changing the value of [method parameter] `n` inside method `SumThem`. I can rewrite method `SumThem` as follows:

```java
public static int SumThem(int n) {
    if (n == 0) {
        return n;
    }
    --n;
    int tmp = SumThem(n);
    return tmp + n;
}
```

The above code is the same as your code, it just does each operation in a separate statement, for example:

```java
SumThem(--n) + n;
```

First `n` is decremented. Then method `SumThem` is called. Then the value returned by method `SumThem` is added to `n`.

Initially the value of `n` is 5, so the above code first changes the value of `n` to 4. Then it calls `SumThem(4)` – which returns 6. Then 6 is added to `n` (which is now 4 since you decremented it before recursively calling `SumThem`). Hence the result is 10 (ten).

What you need to do is **not** change the value of `n`. So your method needs to be:

```
public static int SumThem(int n) {
    if (n == 0) {
        return n;
    }
    return SumThem(n - 1) + n;
}
```